# How is length of string and frequency of sound related in musical instruments like guitar, violin etc? Also differentiate between note and tone

Tags: acoustics, frequency, string, wavelength

I read a sentence that a guitarist set his strings before performance then he is changing frequency of sound. I was wondering in which case frequency will be more, if length of string is large or small. Also I am really confused between note and tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's clear up the terminology.

Pitch means the same as frequency - it is the number of vibrations per second. If a tone contains several harmonics then "pitch" usually means its fundamental pitch.

Tone is the whole waveform that is played. A tone has a fundamental pitch, a series of harmonics, and a length or duration. The fundamental pitch and the harmonics will each have a loudness or intensity, which varies over time. The combination of harmonics and the way in which the intensity of each harmonic varies over time form the "timbre" of the tone. This is what distinguishes one instrument from another. With most instruments, a skilled player can influence the timbre of the tones that they play, adding "expression" to a piece.

Note usually means the symbol for a tone as it is written on the page in a musical score. The note tells the player the pitch and duration of the tone they should play. It can also give additional information on the loudness and the way the note should be played or how it should be connected to notes played before, after or at the same time as this note.

When a guitar player "tunes" their guitar before a performance they are adjusting the "open" pitch of each string by changing the tension on the string. This makes sure that the strings are in tune with one another, and also with any other instruments that will be playing alongside the guitar. When a guitar player actually plays a piece they select the pitch of each tone they play by altering the length of the string that is being played. They do this by placing a finger against a fret on the guitar's neck. The shorter the length of vibrating string, the higher the pitch of the tone that is played.

Answer (score 3):

The tone and frequency of a plucked guitar string is governed by the so-called wave equation:

$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}=\frac{T}{\rho}\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}$$

You can find the full derivation and meaning of symbols [here (my own work)](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=17#pid451284), so now I'll simply summarise.

The **frequency** (pitch) $f$ of a plucked guitar is given by:

$$f_n=\frac{nc}{2L}\tag{1}$$

where $L$ is the length of the string, $n=1,2,3,...$ and $c$ is the root of the ratio of string tension and string linear density:

$$c=\sqrt{\frac{T}{\rho}}\tag{2}$$

$(2)$ tells us that when a musician tunes his instrument, he does so by adjusting the string tension with the screws at the top of the fretboard.

$(1)$ tells us several things:

1. the shorter the string, the higher the pitch (think ukelele!)
2. the string doesn't just generate a single frequency: it generates a whole range of frequencies (frequency spectrum), for $n=1,2,3,...$

*Visualised fundamental and harmonics in a taut string:*

[image: Harmonics]

$f_1$ is generally referred to as the **fundamental**, while $f_2,f_3,f_4,...$ are the **harmonics**, aka the overtones.

With each frequency $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,...$ is associated an **amplitude** $A_i$ or **loudness** (aka 'intensity')

The 'mix' of intensities $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,...$ determines the **tone** or 'timbre' of the note. This so-called **amplitude spectrum** explains why:

1. instruments belonging to a different family, like 'pianos' and 'violins' e.g., sound so distinctly different
2. one 'guitar' doesn't sound exactly like the next one.

I hope this helps.